# Is there a prepared piano in Staier's recording of Diabelli Variations?

Tags: recording, piano, beethoven

In Andreas Staier recording of Beethoven's Diabelli Variations, there is some weird stuff going on throughout variations 22 and 23 [(recording here starts at var 22)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dqtgTDCkYlM#t=31m27s). 
It sounds like there's paper between the strings for some parts of var 22 (or a kazoo?), and he borrowed the percussion section of an orchestra for some bits of var 23.

Does anyone know the inside scoop?  The buzziness in var 22 seems like a nod to the opening bars of [Don Giovanni](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=olZTKM6mIpg) (indeed, the variation is known as "Allegro molto, alla « Notte e giorno faticar » di Mozart").  It reminded me of the fagotti that back up Leporello during his opening complaint "Notte e giorno faticar".  Anything to back up this wild speculation?  What about the cymbal crashes apparent in var 23?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The effects you're asking about are built into the piano itself, activated by pedals. So, "prepared" in the early 19th-century sense (specialty pedals were all the rage), but not in the modern John Cage sense.

This concert review (https://bachtrack.com/review-wigmore-hall-andreas-staier-diabelli-variations) mentions the pedals involved (other CD reviews corroborate), and you can see a demonstration of the Janissary (Turkish purcussion) pedal here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2OjYKvl5raM

For anyone interested in more about these types of pedals, Wikipedia provides a fair starting point (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piano_pedals#Novelty_pedals), with references for further reading.